# Do you need to have credit card when checking-in in hotel

Tags: booking.com

I have a question. If my friend books a hotel via booking.com with his own debit card will everything be fine when I arrive? Will I need to have that credit card or any other specific information?

**UPDATE**

Both hotels that I have stayed in did not require to provide credit card that was used to book rooms via booking.com

Comment: Your friend is making the booking for you to travel alone? Usually the hotel will ask for *a* card at check-in to guarantee incidentals. Do you have a credit/debit card at all?

Comment: No I don't have the credit/debit card.

Comment: Do you have any credit/debit card? It doesn't have to be the one used for the booking

Comment: Generally the hotel will charge the debit/credit card you provide when you check in. The one provided during booking is to charge when you don't show up or cancel after the grace period and the hotel needs to charge you.

Comment: So will I need to have that credit/debit card which my friend used when performing the booking?

Comment: Is the booking pre-paid? You could do with a few more details in your question.

Comment: And what is the country. Some solutions is not possible in Brazil, for example. I sure that a Credit Card Authorization Form is not acceptable in Brazil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have the original credit card your friend used and you don't have a credit card yourself, your friend can send the hotel his approval via a [**credit card authorization form**](https://www.hyatt.com/hyatt/customer-service/ccauth_hotels.pdf).

Basically it can be a photocopy of the front and back of the card with an ID and a signed note from your friend indicating he gives them the hotel authority to charge the card.

I have used it in Dubai for hotels for friends and also airlines when I wasn't with the traveling party.

Answer (score 1):

If the booking is prepaid or if the room is simply guaranteed with a credit card, it doesn't matter. The hotel will ask for a credit card at check-in, to cover additional expenses you may incur. They may or may not be okay with a debit card or cash deposit in lieu of a credit card. For example in China they sometimes will take a couple night's payment as a deposit in cash and you get back any unused funds when you check out (provided you didn't lose the flimsy receipt).

The credit card you present **need not** be the same as the one used to make the booking, and typically when you check out you have another opportunity to either leave any charges on the credit card you gave them or put the charges on a different credit card (or pay cash).